# PlayerPrefs Unity сохранение собранных монет

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я сделал сбор монет и их сохранение в TMP, но тут до меня дошло, что после перезахода в игру, собранные монеты не исчезают. Как бы это логично, я же нигде не указал сохранение того удалена ли монета.

Вот код

```
    [SerializeField] private int GetCoin;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text TextGetCoin;


    private void Awake()
    {
        

        GetCoin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CoinsCount");
        TextGetCoin.text = "Coins:" + GetCoin;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
        {
            GetCoin++;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CoinsCount", GetCoin);
            
            TextGetCoin.text = "Coins:" + GetCoin;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

И вот отсюда вопрос как сохранить, тот факт что монета собрана, чтобы после перезахода она не респавнилась?

Comment: Заведи для каждой монеты ID, и, когда монета собрана, сохраняй его. При загрузке сцены проверяй, если ID есть в PlayerPrefs, значит монету спаунить не нужно. Пожалуй, это самый простой, но не самый быстрый способ.

Comment: Я хотел так сделать, но подумал что это, как это очень неоптимизированно, тем более что монет будет не 10 и не 100, так как это практически открытый мир

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, нужна добавить компонент, который будет отвечать за состояние монеток. C его помощью, мы сможем отключать те монетки, которые были собраны:

```
using System.Text;

internal sealed class EnumerableContainer
{
    [SerializeField] private Coin[] Coins;

    public void SetDeactivateCoin(int id)
    {
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < id; iterator++)
        {
            if (Coins[iterator].Id == id)
            {
                Coins[iterator].State = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity: 256);

        foreach (Coin coin in Coins)
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}:", JsonUtility.ToJson(coin));

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public void FromJson(string data)
    {
        string[] buffer = data.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int iterator = 0;
        foreach (string coinData in buffer)
        {
            Coin coin = JsonUtility.FromJson(coinData);
            Coins[iterator].State = coin.State;

            if (!Coins[iterator].State)
                Coins[iterator].gameObject.SetActive(false);

            iterator++;
        }
    }
}
```

Следующий компонент будет отвечать за сбор самих монет и изменять их состояние:

```
internal sealed class CollectCoinsCounter : Monobehaviour
{
    public event Action<int> OnChangeValue;
    public int GetCountCoin => _coins;

    private int _coins;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.TryGetComponent<Coin>(out Coin coin))
        {
            _coins += coin.Cost;
            coin.State = false;
            coint.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            UpdateText(_coins);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateText(int value)
    {
        OnChangeValue.Invoke(value);
    }

    public void SetCountCoin(int count)
    {
        _coins = count;
    }
}
```

Компонент, который будет отвечать за обновление пользовательского интерфейса:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(CollectCoinsCounter))]
internal sealed class UpdateUI : Monobehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text _text;

    private CollectCoinsCounter _collect;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _collect = GetComponent<CollectCoinsCounter>();
    }

    private void OnEnable() => _collect.OnChangeValue += OnChangeValue;
    private void OnDisable() => _collect.OnChangeValue -= OnChangeValue;

    private void OnChangeValue(int obj)
    {
        _text.text = string.Format("Coins: {0}", obj);
    }
}
```

Один из главных компонентов - сама модель монетки. Такой компонент обязан быть привязан к самим монеткам:

```
internal sealed class Coin : Monobehaviour
{
    public int Id;
    public int Cost;
    public bool State = true;
}
```

И компонент сохранение/загрузки состояние монет:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(EnumerableContainer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CollectCoinsCounter))]
internal sealed class SavedCoin : Monobehaviour
{
    private readonly string _prefName = "CoinsCount";
    private readonly string _prefNameState = "CoinsState";

    private EnumerableContainer _enumerableContainer;
    private CollectCoinsCounter _collect;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _enumerableContainer = GetComponent<EnumerableContainer>();
        _collect = GetComponent<CollectCoinsCounter>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_prefName))
        {
            int count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(_prefName);

            _collect.UpdateText(count);
            _collect.SetCountCoin(count);
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_prefNameState))
            _enumerableContainer.FromJson(PlayerPrefs.GetString(_prefNameState));
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(_prefName, _collect.GetCountCoin);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(_prefNameState, _enumerableContainer.ToJson());
    }
}
```